# how to find right most position in horizontalScrollView

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

Can anyone tell me how to find right most position in `horizontalScrollView`? I am using `setOnTouchListener` to find x and y position.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the Gallery widget, it is a lot more organized.  Unless you have a specific reason for using a custom horizontal scroll view.  Within the Gallery widget you can do something like: `myGal.getPosition(lastIndex);`